# Can I transit through the US with an expired F-1 visa?

Tags: visas, transit, f1-visas

I'm an international student doing a PHD in the USA. Currently my F-1 Visa expired but I have a new I-20 to renew it in my home country Colombia. I have a trip for an India  conference for 10 day starting June 10 and ending June 20. My plan is to go to India from the US and then return to Colombia to renew my Visa but from India to Colombia the flight makes a stop in Newark, and I understand you must have a transit visa to do this. My question is, can I do it with my expired F-1 visa?

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as 'transit' in the US. You actually need to be legally able to enter.

Comment: @MarkMayo So he'll be applying for a B1/B2 in this case? That amount of stuff for so little -_-

Comment: @MarkMayo No wait, This is applicable right? http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/other/transit.html http://www.immihelp.com/visas/transitvisa/c1visa.html

Comment: Added an answer.

Comment: @AdityaSomani that's for people on a B visa - if you have a visa - B, J1, whatever, then in theory you use that to 'transit'. But you still need a valid (not expired) visa of some sort :(

Comment: @MarkMayo What about the C-1 visa. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Like I said, it's still a visa that he'll need to get or qualify for, present documents for, and so on.  The question was about whether or not he could transit with an expired F-1 Visa, and no, he can't.

Comment: @MarkMayo Right, I somehow missed the part of your comment saying that "you still need a valid (not expired) visa of some sort"

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as 'transit' for the US, unfortunately, you need a legal visa to enter.  However, there are some caveats for this.

Firstly, is your visa expired? If so (as yours is), you need a new one:

> If your visa is expired or you have already used the number of
>   entries you are allowed, you will need to apply for a new F-1 visa in
>   order to re-enter the U.S.

However, if you are just passing through to visit certain countries, [there are some exceptions](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/isso/visa/F-1/F-1_travel.html#newF1Visa):

> If you are traveling only to Canada, Mexico or the Caribbean (except
>   Cuba and Bermuda) for fewer than thirty days, you may return to the
>   U.S. with an expired F-1 entry visa in your passport

I went hunting to see what they defined the 'Caribbean' as, but unfortunately, it's [not Colombia](http://international.syr.edu/current-students/Cruise.html).

> If your U.S. F-1 or J-1 visa has expired...limited to only U.S. territories,
>   Canada, Mexico and adjacent islands of the Caribbean, and your
>   combined visits to these countries must be limited to less than 30
>   days.
>
> U.S. Territories in the Caribbean include Puerto Rico and the U.S.
>   Virgin Islands (St. Thomas, St. Croix, and St. John).
>
> Adjacent islands of the Caribbean (as defined in the U.S. Code of
>   Federal Regulations at 8CFR 286.1(a) include:
>
> Anguilla, Antigua, Aruba, Bahamas, Barbados, Barbuda, Bermuda,
>   Bonaire, British Virgin Islands, Cayman Islands, Cuba, Curacao,
>   Dominica, the Dominican Republic, Grenada, Guadeloupe, Haiti, Jamaica,
>   Marie-Galante, Martinique, Miquelon, Montserrat, Saba, Saint
>   Barthelemy, Saint Christopher, Saint Eustatius, Saint Kitts-Nevis,
>   Saint Lucia, Saint Maarten, Saint Martin, Saint Pierre, Saint Vincent
>   and Grenadines, Trinidad and Tobago, Turks and Caicos Islands, and
>   other British, French and Netherlands territory or possessions
>   bordering on the Caribbean Sea.